# Integral evaluation involving trignometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How to explain the following equality? (Part of an integral calculation):

$$\frac{2}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left| \sin x \right| (\cos nx + i\sin nx) dx
= \frac{4}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \sin x \cos nx \cdot dx$$

(Notice the change in the integral range)

Comment: Split the integral into $[-\pi,0]$ and $[0,\pi]$, and also $e^{inx} = \cos nx + i\sin nx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\sin x|\sin(nx)$ is an odd function, so its integral on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ is equal to $0$.

On the other hand $|\sin x|\cos(nx)$ is even. Its integral on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is twice the integral on $[0,\pi]$. The last integral should be from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much!